Как запустить команду flutter pub run build_runner build в Android Studio?
Всем привет. Пытаюсь освоить базу данных Isar на flutter. С импортом зависимостей никаких проблем нет, но вот с запуском генератора в Android Studio проблемы. Если в VC Code у других это получается легко (но я вынужден работать в Android Studio), то в AS - не получается, он не генерирует файл .g.dart. Я как только не писал эту команду в Terminal, и:
flutter pub run build_runner build

и вот так:
$flutter pub run build_runner build

и вот так:
${flutter pub run build_runner build}

Подскажите, возможно ли вообще сгенерировать нормально файл g.dart в Android Studio и как это сделать?

Настройте вашу IDE: https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/android-studio
